# Lower-bounds of running-time for output sensitive Algorithms

Tags: reference-request, time-complexity, runtime-analysis

Let me ask my general question using a specific example, namely range searching:

Given a set of points in the plane and an axis parallel rectangle, report all points lying in the rectangle.

If the rectangle contains $k$ points, then this can be solved in $O(\log n + k)$ time (after some preprocessing). I understand that this is in some sense optimal, but what if the points obey some regularity?

Obviously if they are from the integer grid, this can be solved in constant time.

What is less obvious to me is the situation where the points lie equally spaced on some complicated curves: I could report to the user a set of curve-intervals tuples from which he can deduce the number of points.

But am I actually still solving the problem, or am I just outsourcing the work to the user?

I realize that the question is not very precise and I am not sure if such topics have been studied before. 
I would be interested in any literature reference, where algorithms produce output in a non-explicit way.

Comment: The issue of output sensitivity seems easily resolved by specifying that when you compare the asymptotic runtime of two algorithms that their output be in the same form (or convertible in constant time). If the output of one algorithm requires $O(f(n))$ of work to make it identical to the other for any non-constant $f$ then you can just include the required post-processing as a step in the algorithm when doing runtime analysis. Is this what you are asking or have I misinterpreted?

Comment: @Kaya Thanks for your comment. I guess my question was more along the line: When is a problem considered to be solved? When I enumerate all elements in the solution set or when if give some (complicated) description of the solution

Comment: I am a little confused.  According to the claimed running time, the algorithm can avoid looking at the entire input.  Is there some other assumption, like the points being sorted by x-coordinate?

Comment: @Louis For the claimed running time to hold, the data has to be preprocessed, i.e. a so called Orthogonal Range Tree has to be built.

Comment: @user695652: That makes it more of a data structures question, not really output sensitive algorithms.

Comment: @Louis Well I guess the example in the question without preprocessing wouldn't make much sense because then the runtime would be $O(n+k)$ which is $O(n)$, so the output sensitivity does not come into play.